# ESP8266 programming without USB cable

Tags: esp8266

I have a sensor which is connected to an ESP8266 WiFi module and is supplied power through a MB102 breadboard power supply, which takes its power from wall adapter. It is not connected to a computer physically. It runs on my home WiFi network. I know that I have to run an Arduino IDE but how does the IDE recognize the module and program it?

Comment: "without USB cable" you mean "over the air/wirelessly"?

Comment: You can program it OTA. Arduino IDE has this feature in it. In Tools>Port> you can find your physical as well as network ports. Refer to this website https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-ota-updates-with-arduino-ide-over-the-air/